# javac not recognized command

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-8

I installed java JDK and my environment variables are:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66
Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;etc
```

Java -version:

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)
```

Still, javac is not being recognized

Comment: Welcome to the site!  What error message are you seeing?  Does `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\javac.exe` actually exist? --- Also, check out the tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour for info and a badge :) .

Comment: have you tried putting the java-bin path directly in to the PATH variable? If that doesn't work there is no javac.exe in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin` (or maybe the folder doesn't exist

Comment: Have you actually gone to `C:\Program Files\Java` and *looked*?

Comment: @cxw `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\javac.exe` exists

Comment: have you tried to run `javac -version`? What error do you get?

Comment: Why have you deleted your answer? Wasn't it correct?

Comment: If @Erwin's answer is correct, please accept (hit the checkmark).  Otherwise, one more question - how are you trying to invoke javac?  cmd.exe?  PowerShell?  Windows Explorer?  Please edit your question to show exactly how you are trying to run javac and exactly what error messages (or error dialog boxes) you get.  (Oh, and what version of Windows?)  Thanks!

Comment: @cxw OP already wrote an answer, but deleted it again (that's why I asked him about that in the comment above)

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the runtime only, you need the JDK.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: I guess `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66` is pretty clear that OP uses a JDK ;P.

Comment: Yes. But that is just an environment variable for JAVA_HOME. Is javac actually there?

Comment: `javac` is in the "bin" sub-directoy. What I meant is: OP doesn't need to download a JDK, since he already has one.

Comment: I cannot follow you. How do you know that for sure (based on a environment variable)? I think the OP should check. We all know the confusion that can arrise when you have multiple java versions, or are upgrading.

Comment: "How do you know that for sure (based on a environment variable)?" I can ask you the same about "You have installed the runtime only". Since OP used a full path in his variable I don't think he is making it up (especially the version number in the path). He also posted an answer about the solution, but deleted it.

Comment: I guessed his runtime was installed because that is what his output claimed: "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)". That doesn't mean the compiler is installed, and I don't trust JAVA_HOME. That is possibly a relic from earlier tries.